# Объединение строк DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно сделать такую таблицу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ФИО" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Организация" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding }" HeadersVisibility="None" Margin="-2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Но столкнулся с проблемой привязки данных во вложенной таблице.

Comment: А что из себя представляют привязываемые данные? Покажите код классов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У DataGrid, как впрочем и у любого ItemsControl, все элементы автоматически привязываются к элементы коллекции. Поэтому, если хотите такую вложенность, то создавайте коллекцию из ViewModel, где будут лежать другие коллекции.

```
public ObservavbleCollection<SubVM> Employees;
```

Это коллекция, к которой байндится основная DataGrid,после этого у элемента DataGrid значение DataContext становится автоматом равным SubVM. Остаётся лишь в нем создать ещё одни коллекции.

```
class SubVM
{
   public string Name { get; set; } // На него байндится первый столбец с ФИО
   public ObservableCollection<string> Org { get; set; } // Коллекция названий организаций.
   public ObservableCollection<int> Time { get; set; }  //Коллекция времени работы
}
```

После этого у вложенной таблицы организаций ItemsSource="{Binding Org}"

UPD:
Значит вы что-то делаете не так. Вот мой код, основанный на вашем, в XAML.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="ФИО" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Организация" Width="*">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Org}" Margin="-2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False">
                          <DataGrid.Columns>
                              <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Org" Binding="{Binding}"/>
                          </DataGrid.Columns>
                      </DataGrid>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>

          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Время" Width="*">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Time}" Margin="-2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False">
                          <DataGrid.Columns>
                              <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Time" Binding="{Binding}"/>
                          </DataGrid.Columns>
                      </DataGrid>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Для теста я в конструкторе MainWindow после InitializeComponent() добавляю в коллекцию пару элементов и напрямую выставляю DataContext у окна.

```
SubVM subVM = new SubVM();
subVM.Name = "111";
subVM.Org.Add("Org1");
subVM.Org.Add("Org2");
subVM.Time.Add(3);
subVM.Time.Add(4);

Employees.Add(subVM);

subVM = new SubVM();
subVM.Name = "222";
subVM.Org.Add("Org2");
subVM.Org.Add("Org3");
subVM.Time.Add(5);
subVM.Time.Add(6);

Employees.Add(subVM);

DataContext = Employees;
```

Получилось вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не вижу картинки автора, потому могу ошибаться, но что вы описываете похоже на [группировку данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control)

Comment: @tym32167 не совсем то, его интересует именно визуальное объединение нескольких строк. Чтобы под одним именем в одном столбце было сразу несколько организаций в другом. Хотя, конечно, более красивым решением, было бы то, что по вашей ссылке)

Comment: Благодарю, но такой сценарий я тоже рассматривал и при привязке коллекции с названием организаций я получал не имена, а количество букв в слове. Время не показывается вообще

Comment: Благодарю! Попробую воссоздать на досуге

Comment: Можно подробнее про Employees?